# dissociate colour from group in aesthetic mapping in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to color just the top points

```
data <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100))
data$a <- ifelse(data$x>quantile(data$x,.90),"1","2")
```

But setting the colour aesthetic does the same thing as grouping, except for adding color.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=x,colour=a))+
  geom_point(stat="ecdf")

ggplot(data,aes(x=x,group=a))+
  geom_point(stat="ecdf")
```

Is there a way that I can set the colour aesthetic for the points without having the data grouped for separate computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps calculate the empirical CDF separately and graph the points from it.

```
# reproducible!
set.seed(1492)

data <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100))

# explicitly make the y vals
fx <- ecdf(data$x)
data$y <- fx(data$x)

# point colors
data$a <- ifelse(data$x > quantile(data$x, 0.90), "1", "2")

# take a peek
head(data)
##            x    y a
## 1 -0.5898476 0.31 2
## 2 -0.8986574 0.22 2
## 3 -1.6241110 0.06 2
## 4  1.0479216 0.85 2
## 5 -0.2782887 0.38 2
## 6  0.3624930 0.63 2

gg <- ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=a))
gg <- gg + geom_point()
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Yes, this is the only solution I've found so far for this example of calculating the ecdf, but I wonder if the feature is available more generally. I am beginning to think that it is not.